# Best type/way of scale to start practicing and how to move on?

Tags: guitar, scales, acoustic-guitar, beginner

Learning for past 8 months.. chords are coming up well.. trying now to learn scales (after knowing those are the foundation)...

Started with E chromatic scale (2
octaves across first 4 frets) with metronome... Is that a right place to start... What should I concentrate while playing ? Im playing and saying the name of the note in mind.. when to move on and how to proceed ? Please pour ur thoughts.

My goal is to sing and play any song flawlessly without thinking too much about chords and patterns.

Answer (score 2):

I made 12 spotify playlists with music in each key and play one key at a time while staring at a fretboard map with all the notes placed out. It seems to work fine for me. It worked well for me on piano, after improvising and having fun to music a couple of dozen hours I started to notice patterns, relations and symmetries (hoping same thing happens on guitar).